# Adding data with foreign key in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, foreign-keys

This is my first time working with database so I'm still trying to understand how all this works.
I'm trying to write my data (User, Note, Group) to database. I have three classes.

First one is User:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Group> groups { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.groups = new List<Group>();
    }
}
```

Note:

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content{ get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Group> groups { get; set; }

    }
```

And Group:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

I know I should add foreign key but I don't know where and how. I'm really stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can add a FK if you like, but EF will add one behind the scenes automatically. See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) Also, you don't need `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` - that is the default for an int key.

Comment: [many to many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Before you add foreign key. First you must define the relationship cardinality between each tables. To define it, you can just imagine how each table are represented in real life.

For example, a group can/must contain more than one user. And a user can be inside a single group or more at once.
So we define the relationship between a group and a user as **MANY TO MANY**, unless, you define it so that one user may only be registered to one group. In which case the relationship would become **ONE TO MANY**. With **ONE** being the group table and **MANY** refers to the user table.

Now, once the relationship is defined, usually the foreign key is set in the **MANY** table, in this case, it's the user table. So every user would have a foreign key called "Group".

As for the **MANY TO MANY** relationship the foreign key is set in both table. So that each table contains the key of the other.

Comment: A group can contain more than one user and more than one note and a user, same as a note can be inside one or more groups at once.

Comment: Well in that case, the relationships are all **MANY TO MANY**.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I don't know how to do that in code.

Comment: neither of your objects need a FK property in many to many, as you'll need a join table to flatten this relationship. EF should automatically generate such join table and fill it automatically when you save your objects. If you want more control over how the join table looks like, you can use fluent api with the .HasMany().WithMany().Map() (.ToTable, .MapLeftKey, .MapRightKey) functions.